# function that describes accumulated area between curves?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I'm still a beginner to this so bear with me

I'm trying to create a function that describes the accumulated area between two functions, but I'm having no luck with getting a graph to appear while also being confused on whether my function is correct or not.

Here's what I have so far:

```
A = x /. FindRoot[pred[x] == prey[x], {x, 150}]
B = x /. FindRoot[pred[x] == prey[x], {x, 250}]
preypop := NIntegrate[prey[x] - pred[x], {x, 0, A}] + NIntegrate[pred[x] - prey[x], {x, A, B}] + NIntegrate[prey[x] - pred[x], {x, B, 365}]
```

The plot function only shows an empty graph after taking a while to process. I'd appreciate if someone could also check if the function would actually work because I'm at a loss on what to do.

EDIT: here's the function declaration and plot function

```
prey[t_] := 
 5 (Sin[\[Pi]*t/365])^4 (Cos[\[Pi]*t/365])^2 (5 + Sin[2 \[Pi]*t/365])

pred[t_] := 6 (Sin[\[Pi]*t/365])^6

Plot[{pred[t], prey[t]}, {t, 0, 365}, Filling -> 1 -> {2}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Day of the year", "Population dynamic"}]
```

EDIT2: oh god well this is embarassing (proper functions)

```
prey[t_] := 
 5 (Sin[\[Pi]*t/365])^4 (Cos[\[Pi]*t/365])^2 (5 + Sin[2 \[Pi]*t/365])

pred[t_] := 6 (Sin[\[Pi]*t/365])^6

A = x /. FindRoot[pred[x] == prey[x], {x, 150}]
B = x /. FindRoot[pred[x] == prey[x], {x, 250}]

preypop := 
 NIntegrate[prey[x] - pred[x], {x, 0, A}] + 
  NIntegrate[pred[x] - prey[x], {x, A, B}] + 
  NIntegrate[prey[x] - pred[x], {x, B, 365}]

Plot[preypop[x], {x, 0, 365}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Please provide the whole code you are using, including definitions of ``pred`` and ``prey``.

Comment: To add the comment by @Domen please provide the definitions for `pred` and `prey`, but also give us the `Plot` command to which you are referring. In the code you provided there's only a numerical integration, no `Plot` whatsoever.

Comment: @Domen ok i added those things in

Comment: The plot appears as expected. Have you tried the code in a fresh Mathematica session?

Comment: @SimonWoods oof sorry for making you run in a circle i posted the wrong graph function. The newest edit should be the segment i'm actually referring to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your definition of `preypop`, I assume you want to calculate $\int \left|{\rm prey}(x) - {\rm pred}(x)\right| \, \mathrm d x$.

It turns out that for non-analytical integrals, it is usually more efficient to use `NDSolve` instead of `Integrate`.

```
sol = NDSolve[{y'[x] == Abs[pred[x] - prey[x]], y[0] == 0}, y[x], {x, 0, 365}];
Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 365}]
```

[image: NDSolve]

Comment: thanks for answering, i don't think i would ever have been able to figure that out on my own.